# 404 page of TYPO3 results page not found error

Tags: typo3, http-status-code-404, typo3-10.x

I have upgraded my website from TYPO3 9.5 to 10.4. After that my 404-page results in the following Page not found error.

[image: error]

[image: error handling]

```html
base: /
baseVariants: {  }
errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=478'
```

Comment: Did you make sure that page id=478 is active and accessible?

Comment: Yes, the page is active. But I can't view this 404 page(showing the same error). When I tried to disable the page, the error is gone but all other pages are showing content from the root page. Why this happened??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution by recreating the sites configuration.